# How to get just the last added doc from a whole collection. OnSnapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get just de last document added in a specific collection. Reading the docs i got the following code:

```
db.collection("Orders")
.onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.docChanges.forEach(function(change) {
        if (change.type === "added") {
            console.log("New order: ", change.doc.data());
        }
        if (change.type === "modified") {
            console.log("Modified order: ", change.doc.data());
        }
        if (change.type === "removed") {
            console.log("Removed order: ", change.doc.data());
        }
    });
});
```

But its bring more than one doc. bring all because its read like all are new.
To make context, its a orders db, so i need the app to be listen for the last order added, not all. 
I'll really appreciate any help!
Thansk!

Comment: How do you define exactly what is the "last" document?  If you don't have a query that gets you just that document, by whatever criteria you define, you're always going to fetch every document every time.

Comment: I need the last document added into the collection. I guess you say it because the forEach, I would change it but do not know which should i use.

Comment: You will need to add a timestamp to the document, then query that document using that timestamp field.  Documents in a collection don't have a natural time ordering that you can query without a filter.

Comment: thanks. Can you make an example? how should i filter by the last timestamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firestore has no built-in concept of most recent, or at least not in a way you can filter on. So to allow you to retrieve the most recent document, you must first add a timestamp to each document. I'd recommend using a server-side timestamp for that, with something like this:

```
ordersCollection.add({
  ..., // all your other fields
  timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});
```

With that in place, you can get the most recent document by ordering and limiting:

```
db.collection("Orders")
.orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
.limit(1)
.onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, doc.data());
    });
});
```